# work around for former CStringIO and String IO function in Python 3 Pdfinterp (Pdfminer)

Tags: python, c-strings, pdfminer

I am using the pdfminer tool to convert pdf to .csv (text) and one of the subcommands in the tool `pdfinterp.py` still uses the CStringIO and StringIO for string to string translation -

```
import re
try:
    from CStringIO import StringIO 
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO
```

I am using Python 3 so I am aware of the need to change to io and io.StringIO.

How exactly should the above command be re-worded in `pdfinterp` to make it functional in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

you could extend your import block to make it compatible with all versions (Python 2.x or 3.x). Ugly because of all try/except blocks but would work

```
try:
    from CStringIO import StringIO 
except ImportError:
    try:
        from StringIO import StringIO
    except ImportError:
        from io import StringIO
```

or (slightly better)

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3,)
   try:
       from CStringIO import StringIO 
   except ImportError:        
        from StringIO import StringIO
else:
     from io import StringIO
```

Be aware that python 3 has `BytesIO` too because binary data and text data is different now. So if `StringIO` is used to pass binary data it will fail.

Comment: Got past it with your first suggestion - THX